# variable's scope after visiting a page with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Noob here: 
I have a small script to collect all product links from an user Ebay product list and then open them one by one.
It populates the list correctly, it opens the first link as expected, waits a bit and then returns to the previous page (the product list).

When trying to open the next link in the list it crashes because although the list still contains the same number of elements, the content changed: it doesn't hold ANY links.

I have tried debugging, tried to bring more persistence by making the list global (IMO superfluous) and all to no avail. I've checked around and didn't noticed anyone with a similar problem.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.maximize_window()
    # navigate to the application home page
    driver.get("http://www.ebay.de/sch/living_food/m.html/")
    # populate with the list of product links
    global link_name
    link_name=driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//[@id='ListViewInner']/li/h3/a")

    def list_review():
        print "Found " + str(len(link_name)) + " products:"
        for link in link_name:
            print link.text
            linkproduct= link.get_attribute('href')
            print linkproduct
        print

    def open_product(link):
        print "Now testing: " + link.text
        linkproduct = link.get_attribute('href')
        print "with the link: " + linkproduct
        link.click()
        # driver.get(linkproduct)
        print "wait 2 seconds"
        driver.implicitly_wait(2)
        print "return to product list and perform a little health check"
        driver.back()
        print "The list has " + str(len(link_name)) + " elements"

    list_review()

    print "Let's open the links one by one"
    for link in link_name:
        open_product(link)
        print "We are back! Time for a list check! Still " + str(len(link_name)) + " elements"
        print "I've just done: " + link.text
        print

    driver.quit()
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you leave the current page, or even if the DOM is refreshed, the `driver` "losses" the web elements and you get `StaleElementReferenceException`.

To iterate over several pages you need to relocate the list each iteration, and you can use indexes to keep your location in the list

```
links_len = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//[@id='ListViewInner']/li/h3/a"))
for i in range(links_len):
    link_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//[@id='ListViewInner']/li/h3/a")
    open_product(link_name[i])
    print "We are back! Time for a list check! Still " + str(len(links_len)) + " elements"
    print "I've just done: " + link_name[i].text
```

Comment: You, Sir, are a gentlemen and a scholar! Thanks!

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept it as the answer. Thanks!